# PowerShell to create folders with a specific format

Tags: powershell

I need to create folders called:

```
Week1-Sat
Week1-Sun
Week2-Sat
...
WeekX-Sat
WeekX-Sun
```

creating them manually would take too long.

I need to be able to quickly create empty directories and allow the permissions to be inherited from the parent folder.
(These folders get created and deleted often)

Comment: What have you tried, where are you having problems with?

Answer (score 2):

You just need two nested loops:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\02\08\SF_952895.ps1
$AbbreviatedDayNames = [System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames

for ($Week=1;$Week -lt 53;$Week++){
    0..6|ForEach-Object{
        $Folder = "Week{0}-{1}" -f $Week,$AbbreviatedDayNames[$_]
        New-Item $Folder -ItemType Directory
    }
}
```

For inheritance/propagation see this [Q&A on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282656/setting-inheritance-and-propagation-flags-with-set-acl-and-powershell)